# Where questions receiving close votes go?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

I've recently asked a question on StackOverflow and it suddenly disappeared. Once I found the link on my history and accessed it, I noticed that it had a "**(2)**" near the close link.

Well, though I think that viewing what's the reason for close votes would be helpful for me, I'm not complaining on why it's being closed. What I want to know is: where is it!

If it doesn't even appear on my page, nor on the tag pages, how will people know if it really needs to be closed, or there is an answer for it? Does moderators have a special page where it is possible to see those "being closed" questions?

Comment: They go to a special place in the sky, along with your flushed goldfish and childhood doggies.

Comment: If you click on "close" you can see what categories the pending close votes are in *without* casting a vote to close. If they are in "off-topic" you can click that to get a more detailed list (still *without* casting a close vote). Confusing interface, but it works. Just be sure to chose "cancel" when you're done. This only works on your own questions until you have 3k rep. At 10k you can also get a summary on the tools:close tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean this question. It has 2 close votes as you said.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686929/installing-gnu-packages

It is on page 2 on question list of your profile, ordered by votes (which is default)

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/557306/sidyll#qpage_2-anpage_1-qsort_votes-ansort_votes

You just need to click the button of page <kbd>**2**</kbd> or <kbd>**next**</kbd>

[image]